# jQuery token input on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to use the jQuery token input plugin with Rails and Mongoid.

Using [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) Railscast as a reference I added the plugin to my app
and I setup the various methods, etc.

I created a method on my model that should return this data:

```
class TheModel
    def token_inputs
        { :id => _id, :name => name }
    end
end
```

In my controller I do this:

```
class TheModelsController < ApplicationController
    @models = TheModel.all

    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @models.map(&:token_inputs) }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed. I missed a comma in my JavaScript. Silly me.